# How to take the last line and copy the required columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I would welcome any help with getting a script to work on Form onSubmit to then take the last line (New Form submitted information) from the sheet 'New Orders' to then copy the required columns into the 'DIBOND ORDERS' sheet so it will automatically place the required product for the new customers order onto the required order sheet to be ordered from the different suppliers.

As we have a few different suppliers for clothing, pavements stands, display products.

My Current Code Is

```
   function onEdit() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
var r = ss.getActiveRange();
if(s.getName() == "New Orders" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == "DIBOND") {

    var row = r.getRow();

    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();

    var TSS = ss.getSheetByName("DIBOND ORDERS");
             var lastRow = TSS.getLastRow()+1;
      var cntr = 0
    s.getRange(row,2).copyTo(TSS.getRange(lastRow + cntr,1), {contentsOnly:true});
    s.getRange(row,5).copyTo(TSS.getRange(lastRow + cntr,2), {contentsOnly:true});
    s.getRange(row,6).copyTo(TSS.getRange(lastRow + cntr,4), {contentsOnly:true});
    s.getRange(row,4).copyTo(TSS.getRange(lastRow + cntr,8), {contentsOnly:true});
    s.getRange(row,7).copyTo(TSS.getRange(lastRow + cntr,5), {contentsOnly:true});
    s.getRange(row,8).copyTo(TSS.getRange(lastRow + cntr,6), {contentsOnly:true});
    s.getRange(row,9).copyTo(TSS.getRange(lastRow + cntr,7), {contentsOnly:true});
    //s.deleteRow(row);
}}
```

This Works Prefect if I am on the sheet as a On Edit Function but cannot get it to activate as On Form Submit function.

I have been trying find a way to remove the Active Sheet, Active Range... to be set for the get Last Row by using

```
 SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getRangeByName("New Orders");
```

Starting to think that it cannot be done or I am missing something.

Would be truly grateful for any help.

Thank you in advance Russell.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the last line on the active spreadsheet ( the one onEdit was called ) and the sheet named "DIBOND ORDERS".

```
function getLastLine(){ 
  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DIBOND ORDERS");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange(); // gets all the data. 
  var values = range.getValues();
  Logger.log("LAST ROW : " + values[values.length -1] );
}
```